# Compile-time weaving configuration

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, aop, aspectj

I am trying to convert my load-time-woven aspectj to compile-time-woven.

So I removed `<context:load-time-weaver/>` from my spring config, and added an aspectj compiler to my `pom.xml`. But I don't know how to convert the info in `META-INF/aop.xml`.

I have something like this in there:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
        "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in this package -->
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <!-- use only this aspect for weaving -->
        <concrete-aspect name="MyAspect_" extends="hu.myAspect">
        <pointcut name="pointcut" expression="execution(public * javax.persistence.EntityManager.*(..)) || execution(public * hu..*.create(..))"/>
        </concrete-aspect>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no exact equivalent to aop.xml in compile-time weaving, but you can configure the [AspectJ maven plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html) to [include and exclude certain aspects](https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/includeExclude.html) like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/TransationAspect.java</include>
            <include>**/SecurityAspect.aj</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/logging/*.aj</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I believe you have to specify basedir - if you run this with -X argument it's what it tells you. In my case, I had to put there <basedir>${basedir}/src/main/java</basedir>

Comment: For anyone stumbling overt his: The link has changed to https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/includeExclude.html